# How to repartition of Samsung Galaxy Core GT 18262 By adb?

Tags: samsung

My phone storage is 8GB but my phone showing I have System storage is 1.5 & Internal storage is 1GB. Please how I fix it.

Comment: Please install [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo&hl=en) and post the screenshot (app's output) here. Also, when an OEM says a device has XGB of storage, then it means all the partitions will be covered under this storage. [Somebody](http://www.junglee.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Core-GT-I8262-White/dp/B00D8WDF22) mentioned that 5GB is available for Internal SD-card alone. // Do post the screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

You cant repartition using adb. You will have to use Odin (the samsung flash tool).
Get Odin.
Download or create partition information file (PIT) and flash that using odin.
Ofcourse your data will be wiped out.

If you decide or have to create partition file yourself, you can use [EFS professional](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/orig-development/tool-updated-09-06-14-efs-professional-t1308546)/[PIT Magic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1916936) for that. Just be extra careful and make sure you do your research. Corrupt partition data is never a good thing.

Also, I kinda didnt get how you could get just 1 GB as usable internal memory, it will probably help if you connect your phone to adb and run the command `adb shell df`and post here output. But again, if you feel like you must repartition, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You may try another app named  [AppMgr III](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) and clear all the data using that app, or go with any other storage analyser app. I used [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) and AppMgr for my Samsung Galaxy Grand 2.